# My server is sending me huge amounts of email from root@domain.com, how can I diagnose this issue?

Tags: linux, debian, email-server, sendmail, debian-lenny

I am the admin and I am getting email on my personal email address, I am getting over 1000 emails per hour with "Test mail" subject line. I have checked as many scripts as i could but cannot figure out what i sending these emails, everything was working fine a couple of days back.

Please help this is very very urgent!

Which linux utilities send you email with "test mail" subject? How can search for my personal email address across all files and folders in linux to pin point which script is sending thsi email?

Answer (score 1):

Try to sniff that port for outgoing messages (tcpdump). Than you will know what is the source port. Check in netstat after that.

hint: `tcpdump -ni eth0 dst port 25 -s0 -A`

Also, you can check the headers, maybe there is the signature. Are the messages sent from your mail server or to your mail server? If are sent to your mail server, in tcpdump change `dst` with `src`